# Warning - value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I get the warning when i run this code. I tried all possible solutions I can think of, but cannot get rid of it. Kindly help !

A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

```
import math
task2_df['price_square'] = None
i = 0
for row in data.iterrows():
    task2_df['price_square'].at[i] = math.pow(task2_df['price'][i],2)
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, I don't see your error on Pandas v0.19.2 (tested with code at the bottom of this answer). But that's probably irrelevant to solving your issue. You should *avoid* iterating rows in Python-level loops. NumPy arrays which are used by Pandas are specifically designed for numerical computations:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'price': [54.74, 12.34, 35.45, 51.31]})
df['price_square'] = df['price'].pow(2)

print(df)

   price  price_square
0  54.74     2996.4676
1  12.34      152.2756
2  35.45     1256.7025
3  51.31     2632.7161
```

---

Test on Pandas v0.19.2 with no warnings / errors:

```
import math

df = pd.DataFrame({'price': [54.74, 12.34, 35.45, 51.31]})
df['price_square'] = None
i = 0

for row in df.iterrows():
    df['price_square'].at[i] = math.pow(df['price'][i],2)
    i += 1
```

Comment: Thank You JPP. I found the error finally. I am creating a new dataframe as df1 = df2[[list of columns]]. I took a copy of it and the warning vanished.